# OIDC authorize "display" parameter usage

Tags: openid-connect, display, authorize

What is the point of display parameter in /authorize call of OIDC? Following is what spec says about OIDC parameter. However /authorize invocation is a redirection from client and whether a popup is opened by user-agent or user-agent changes URL on address bar is purely at client side. How /authorize endpoint will use "display" parameter?

**display**
OPTIONAL. ASCII string value that specifies how the Authorization Server displays the authentication and consent user interface pages to the End-User. The defined values are:

**page**
The Authorization Server SHOULD display the authentication and consent UI consistent with a full User Agent page view. If the display parameter is not specified, this is the default display mode.

**popup**
The Authorization Server SHOULD display the authentication and consent UI consistent with a popup User Agent window. The popup User Agent window should be of an appropriate size for a login-focused dialog and should not obscure the entire window that it is popping up over.

**touch**
The Authorization Server SHOULD display the authentication and consent UI consistent with a device that leverages a touch interface.

**wap**
The Authorization Server SHOULD display the authentication and consent UI consistent with a "feature phone" type display.
The Authorization Server MAY also attempt to detect the capabilities of the User Agent and present an appropriate display.
If an OP receives a display value outside the set defined above that it does not understand, it MAY return an error or it MAY ignore it; in practice, not returning errors for not-understood values will help facilitate phasing in extensions using new display values.